# Google Books listVolumes Results

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, google-api-php-client

I am using Codeigniter and the [Google API Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started) and attempting to return the details for a single book via an ISBN lookup.

It works and I am able to retrieve the data, but for some reason I receive more than one result. For example my existing code is:

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $client->setDeveloperKey("MyKey");
    $service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
    $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('0751538310');
        $data = array(
        'gresult'   => $results 
        );
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('item_list', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

**View**

```
<?php 
   foreach ($gresult as $item) {
       echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
   }
?>
```

This returns the following:

```
Panic
Swiss News
Simply Irresistible
Ein perfekter Freund
```

The [direct Google URL](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=0751538310) returns similar results.

Any idea why this is happening? I only require the first result.

Thanks